# Scala:IndexOutOfBoundsException happened when mapping

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm using Scala 2.10.3 with Java 1.7.0_45 (64bit) under Windows
In my code

```
List.range(0, 10) map {ListBuffer[Int]()}
```

throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. But on the other hand,

```
List.range(0, 10) map {i => ListBuffer[Int]()}
```

works well.

So I wonder why it happens? Is there any difference between the two expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListBuffer[T]`'s apply method looks up the element at the given index. You can therefore treat a `ListBuffer[T]` as a function `Int => T`:

```
val buf = ListBuffer[Int](1, 2, 3);
val f: Int => Int = buf
val i = f(1)    //i == 2
```

Your first example is therefore passing to `map` a function which looks up the element at a given index in an empty list buffer i.e. it is equivalent to

```
List.range(0, 10) map {i => ListBuffer[Int]()(i)}
```

hence the exception.

Comment: To clarify: `ListBuffer[A]` (and all other `Seq`s) actually inherit from `(Int) => A` - it won't work for just anything with an `apply` method

Answer (score 3):

@Lee is right, alternatively use fill method:

```
List.fill(10) {ListBuffer[Int]()}
```

this line produces 10 empty ListBuffers